# InputArray as parameter in Emgu CV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

There are many functions in Emgu CV which need InputArray. For example:

```
var r = new Mat();
var t = new Mat();
CvInvoke.SolvePnP(b3D, b2D, _cM, _dC, r, t);
```

What types of ***r*** and ***t*** can I use instead of Mat?

For example, in C++ OpenCV it is possible to use std::vector where InputArray is needed

```
std::vector<Point2f> vec;
// points or a circle, somegow fill it
cv::transform(vec, vec, cv::Matx23f(0.707, -0.707, 10, 0.707, 0.707, 20));
```

Answer (score 3):

I’ve struggled a bit with InRange and the required InputArrays, found this solution:

```
CvInvoke.InRange(image, new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(0, 0, 0)), new ScalarArray(new MCvScalar(0, 0, 0)), imgRed);
```

(https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_Windows_10_Installation_Tutorial/blob/master/RedBallTracker.cs)

Not familiar with SolvePnP so I don’t know if it’s what you need, but maybe it can be of some help...

Comment: Thanks. And what about OutputArray, can it be replaced by something like that?

Comment: I have used a few different functions that expects a parameter that implements the interface IOutputArray, so far I know these classes implements the interface: Mat, VectorOfFloat, VectorOfPoint, VectorOfPointF, VectorOfUMat, VectorOfVectorOfDMatch, RotationMatrix2D, CudaImage. I have tried to make a complete search in the EmguCV namespace using the object browser in VS to find all Classes that implements this interface but have not succeeded unfortunately. /Jonatan